# Running SQL Queries on an array of table names

Tags: php, sql

I'm new to SQL and I currently have an array of strings which represent the names of tables in my database. I want to run a query like this while looping through the table names :

```
$sql = "UPDATE $tablename SET name = '$name', id ='$id' WHERE rank = '$rank'";
```

However, this did not work and i've read that using this type of method above could present SQL injections.

Can anyone recommend a way to work around this, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you a general idea. To address the SQL injection I suggest you investigate prepared queries using PDO or some other library. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

```
foreach($tables as $tablename){
    $sql = "UPDATE $tablename SET name = '$name', id ='$id' WHERE rank = '$rank'";
    // execute query
}
```

Comment: i'm currently using mysqli would this be applicable as well?

Comment: mysqli has its own way of preparing queries. Here's an example from the docs on binding parameters to your prepared query:
    `$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO CountryLanguage VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");`
    `$stmt->bind_param('sssd', $code, $language, $official, $percent);`

This should help:  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysqli_real_escape_string` function on all variables (preferably `$name` and `$rank`) and it will escape any quotes that can cause sql injection.

[Function Reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Comment: from looking at the info in the link above, i see that the mysqli_real_escape_string function is used on variables associated with the connection. However in my code, $name and $rank are derived from other means (parsing fields of a json string)

Answer (score -2):

you are right, your method is very insecure.

go through this list and pick what works better for you: [Good PHP ORM Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108699/good-php-orm-library)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: well i assumed that if one knows about sql injections he should know about loops. and in that case my answer answers the question better than the other 2.